# Magento 2: How to Filter a Product Collection By Store ID

Tags: php, magento2, collection

Using a product factory object, I'm able to create a product, grab a product collection, and fetch the first item of that collection

```
/* var $productFactory \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory */
$product = $this->productFactory->create()->getCollection()->getFirstItem();
```

However, if I attempt to add a store_id to the collection's filter

```
    $product = $this->productFactory
        ->create()
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', 1)
        ->getFirstItem();
```

I get the following error

```
Invalid attribute name: store_id
#0 /Users/alanstorm/Sites/magento-2-dev-docs.dev/magento2/app/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(1434): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->_addAttributeJoin('store_id', 'inner')
#1 /Users/alanstorm/Sites/magento-2-dev-docs.dev/magento2/app/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(359): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->_getAttributeConditionSql('store_id', 1, 'inner')
#2 /Users/alanstorm/Sites/magento-2-dev-docs.dev/magento2/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php(1489): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->addAttributeToFilter('store_id', 1, 'inner')
#3 /Users/alanstorm/Sites/magento-2-dev-docs.dev/magento2/app/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(382): Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Collection->addAttributeToFilter('store_id', 1)
...
#63 {main}
```

The same thing happens if I attempt to use a product repository to filter by store_id (the repositories use the collections under the hood).

Is this a bug?  Or has the relationships between stores, websites, and products                 changed in Magento 2 such that that this is no longer a legitimate query?  Both?  Neither?  Something else?

Comment: I'm very new to M2, but can't you use this https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Collection/AbstractCollection.php#L92?

Comment: @fnng Use method to know, but I want to say "please get me a list of all the products that are part of store X".  Not sure how setStoreId would do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with the method `addStoreFilter()`, see [`Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection#addStoreFilter()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php#L876)

the `addStoreFilter()` function will accept store ID or `Store` object as a parameter.

EG, to get all products for the **current** store:

```
public function getProducts(){
    return $this->collection->addStoreFilter($this->_storeManager->getStore()); 
}
```

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: Thanks @amitbeta!  If you have a moment — do you know if it's possible to create  a store filter using product repositories?  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91278/magento-2-can-you-filter-by-store-id-using-a-product-repository

Comment: sure.. i will look

Comment: @AmitBera, Please can you explain little bit how to use  addStoreFilter() to product collection.

Answer (score 5):

For now this looks like a bug, because there is no possibility to apply store filter with the `ProductRepository::getList()` method, passing store id as a filter of **SearchCriteria**.

In the getList implementation, you can find that all the filters from **SearchCriteria** applied to collection

```
    foreach ($searchCriteria->getFilterGroups() as $group) {
        $this->addFilterGroupToCollection($group, $collection);
    }
```

In `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::addFilterGroupToCollection` there is special handling for **Category filter**, but there is no one for Store.

So, additional condition should be added to `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::addFilterGroupToCollection` which checks whether we have store filter and if we have - set store id for collection, something like:

```
        if ($filter->getField() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::STORE_ID) {
            $collection->setStore($filter->getValue());
            continue;
        }
```

Created internal bug for this issue, its number is **MAGETWO-45950**

Comment: Any news on that? I cannot find a reference to the ticket number on Github.

Comment: In Magento 2 products are assign to Websites, not to Stores. So,  initial behavior described by  Alan is correct, as Product entity doesn't have Store Id link, just link to Website Id. And Internal ticket is about introduction of Extension attribute with ProductWebsiteLinkInterface into the ProductInterface

Comment: Besides store/website association, doesn't `setStore()` also specify which store specific attribute values are fetched? Or is this done in a different way now?

Comment: There are setStoreId/getStoreId methods in Product model implementation, but there are no ones in ProductInterface, so it's not recommended to rely on them in your business logic.

Comment: For now resolving for StoreView level values (for example, localization of attributes) made by StoreID URL part in REST APIs

Comment: So, what do I do if I need a collection of products with values for a specific store in my business logic? OK, I guess I'll look how it's done in the REST API and post a new question if there's still something unclear. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Follow-up: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120385/proper-way-to-get-product-collection-with-store-specific-values-in-admin-area

Answer (score 1):

1) The class is `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection`:

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection $collection */
$collection = $this->categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToSelect('*');
```

2) Then the method is `$collection->setStoreId(0);`

Comment: P.S. instead of 0 you may  put your store id 1, 2, ...

Comment: Meta: For some reason star symbol was removed from my message here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom model with several tables add table_name like: `addFieldToFilter('**table_name.**column_name', 1)`

Comment: Could you please share the whole snippet for loading the product collection from my column say entity id, as you have said above