# How can I extend the category products Rest API?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, category-products, extend

/V1/categories/(cat ID)/products

This API provides very less detail of all the products.

```
{
    "sku": "Nike 3 color half sleeve tshirt",
    "position": 1,
    "category_id": "3"
  },
  {
    "sku": "Louis Phillipe Blue Jean Size 32",
    "position": 1,
    "category_id": "3"
  },
  {
    "sku": "Louis Phillipe Shirt Size M",
    "position": 1,
    "category_id": "3"
  },
  {
    "sku": "UCB shirt Size ",
    "position": 1,
    "category_id": "3"
  },
```

I can use the sku in a search filter to get all the produts with these sku's. But is there a better way around ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use filter by `category_id` during request to Product Repository:

`GET <base_url>/rest/V1/products`

If it is necessary to filter by `store_id` or `website_id` at the same time, see workaround [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/91290/697).

Comment: For this I have to extend the API ? or is it possible by applying filters in the HTTP GET request itself ?

Comment: Filter by `category_id` should work out of the box. The other 2 need a plugin for now, but this will be fixed in core in future releases.

Comment: category_id can be used inside HTTP request ? I am on my way to work and cant run this query: http://192.168.1.180/magento/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq... can you check

Comment: Yes, should work like this.

Comment: It worked.. Its strange though. The response does not have any key named "category_id".. Can you take a look at this one: https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/How-to-use-V1-search-to-get-the-names-and-SKU-s-of-the-magento/td-p/24619

Comment: This is a separate question (create a new one), there is partial response mechanism, which allows this.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94529/how-to-use-v1-search-to-get-the-names-and-skus-of-the-magento-products

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33273/discussion-between-nil-and-alex-paliarush).