# How to use V1/search to get the names and SKU's of the magento products

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, search-criteria

How to use V1/search to get the names and SKU's of the magento products?

I need a text based search to get the names and SKU's of the magento products. While using V1/products API, the response is too much. I just need the name and the SKU, just like google suggestions come up when you type something.

I tried wit the V1/search api but no luck:http://192.168.1.180/magento/index.php/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%nike%&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `V1/products` instead of `V1/search` and add `fields=items[sku],items[name]` GET parameter to the request URL. This allows to get only requested fields in the response.

Comment: tried this... but error..http://192.168.1.180/magento/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%nike%&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like&fields=product[sku]

Comment: In your case should help `fields=sku,name`, `fields=product[sku]` is fake one just to show how to use nested case.

Comment: tried with /products and /search but error ...http://192.168.1.180/magento/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%nike%&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like&fields=sku

Comment: What is the result, if you don't specify `fields` parameter?

Comment: sorry i didn't understand

Comment: I have another question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94697/using-searchcriteria-while-searching-attributes-in-magento-2-0