# Using searchCriteria while searching attributes in magento 2.0

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento2, api, rest-api, search-criteria

Fetching attribute info, if I apply multiple filters in a single search criteria, it does not work. But in case of single filter it works perfectly.

Multiple filters HTTP request:

http://192.168.1.180/magento/index.php/rest/V1/products/attributes?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=attribute_code&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=color&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=attribute_code&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=size&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][condition_type]=eq

```
Output: 
{
  "items": [],
  "search_criteria": {
    "filter_groups": [
      {
        "filters": [
          {
            "field": "attribute_code",
            "value": "size",
            "condition_type": "eq"
          },
          {
            "field": "attribute_code",
            "value": "color",
            "condition_type": "eq"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "total_count": 0
}
```

But when I hit the single filter one, I get results for both size as well as color.

Single filter:

http://192.168.1.180/magento/index.php/rest/V1/products/attributes?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=attribute_code&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=color&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq

UPDATE: Tried the in filter but still no results

```
{
  "items": [],
  "search_criteria": {
    "filter_groups": [
      {
        "filters": [
          {
            "field": "attribute_code",
            "value": "color,size",
            "condition_type": "in"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "total_count": 0
}
```

UPDATE 2: Tried "in" in different filters

```
{
  "items": [],
  "search_criteria": {
    "filter_groups": [
      {
        "filters": [
          {
            "field": "attribute_code",
            "value": "color",
            "condition_type": "in"
          },
          {
            "field": "attribute_code",
            "value": "size",
            "condition_type": "in"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "total_count": 0
}
```

UPDATE 3: Tried "in" filter in separate filter groups

```
{
  "items": [],
  "search_criteria": {
    "filter_groups": [
      {
        "filters": [
          {
            "field": "attribute_code",
            "value": "color",
            "condition_type": "in"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "filters": [
          {
            "field": "attribute_code",
            "value": "size",
            "condition_type": "in"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "total_count": 0
}
```

Comment: What is expected output and what you get?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: @AlexPaliarush did you find anything on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix for the "in" problem, this will probably be fixed in next release: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/65819d2f61a63e4fa9fc978220f8662ee5472791

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the same field is used in 2 filters of the same filter group. In this particular case replace 2 `eq` filters with one `in` filter:

```
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=attribute_code&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=color,size&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=in
```

Comment: I tried but still no results 

'{
  "items": [],
  "search_criteria": {
    "filter_groups": [
      {
        "filters": [
          {
            "field": "attribute_code",
            "value": "color,size",
            "condition_type": "in"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "total_count": 0
}'

Comment: Request seems to be correct. What if specify separately 'in' filter with value 'color' and then value 'size'?

Comment: Edited question with both the API response

Comment: I meant `searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=attribute_code&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=color&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=in`

Comment: but for this I have to access this API n times if I have n attributes?

Comment: Yes, this is just to understand if `in` works for you at all or not.

Comment: yes `in` works fine.

Comment: Also please take a look at this one too: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95314/categoryid-not-there-while-searching-for-products-via-api-2-0-v1-products

Comment: Just tried to apply 2 'eq' filters for single field, cannot make them work for product attributes API. 'in' filter does not work either. Created internal ticket for this (MAGETWO-47450).

Comment: How can I subscribe or track to this ticket?

Comment: Not sure you can track internal tickets, but you can create a ticket [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues) and put as a note that MAGETWO-47450 and MAGETWO-47451 are created internally.