# category_ids attribute missing while searching for products via REST API (rest/V1/products)

Tags: product, category, magento2, rest-api

The response does not have the "category_ids" key. I need this key. Is there any other API which can provide this key?

```
  "id": 10,
  "sku": "Nike 3 color half sleeve tshirt",
  "name": "Nike 3 color half sleeve tshirt",
  "attribute_set_id": 4,
  "price": 0,
  "status": 1,
  "visibility": 4,
  "type_id": "configurable",
  "created_at": "2015-12-01 23:05:47",
  "updated_at": "2015-12-25 00:22:27",
  "weight": 2,
  "product_links": [],
  "options": [],
  "tier_prices": [],
  "custom_attributes": [
    {
      "attribute_code": "description",
      "value": "<p>Nike summer wear hal sleeve tshirt in 3 colors</p>"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "meta_title",
      "value": "Nike 3 color half sleeve tshirt"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "meta_keyword",
      "value": "Nike 3 color half sleeve tshirt"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "meta_description",
      "value": "Nike 3 color half sleeve tshirt <p>Nike summer wear hal sleeve tshirt in 3 colors</p>"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "image",
      "value": "/p/w/pwp_sheet2.jpeg"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "small_image",
      "value": "/p/w/pwp_sheet2.jpeg"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
      "value": "/p/w/pwp_sheet2.jpeg"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "options_container",
      "value": "container2"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "required_options",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "has_options",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "url_key",
      "value": "nike-3-color-half-sleeve-tshirt"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
      "value": "2"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "vendor",
      "value": "Paxcel Cloth House"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

`category_ids` is not joined when list of products is loaded. There are two options to get it:

1. Get list of product IDs, then load each one separately (when requesting `GET rest/V1/products/:sku`, `category_ids` attribute is loaded)
2. Add plugin for `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::getList` which will populate it

Comment: Hey, can you elaborate on how to add a plugin?

Comment: Take a look at the [official docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Comment: hi, as per the documentation I have to modify the di.xml file of a particular module. I found the di.xml in `\Magento\Catalog\Api\di.xml` directory. Is this the one..

Comment: You can create `di.xml` in your custom module, eventually `di.xml` from all modules are collected and merged together (by areas). It is not a good idea to modify core files because this will cause problems during upgrade.

Comment: Ok so I have to add a new module and the plugin is a part of that module

Comment: I think I have to follow this tutrial first: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643 ??

Comment: That one is for Magento 1, better to search for 'plugin' in core `di.xml` files and check how it is implemented there. Also look at [this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/91290/697) and [this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/91382/697)

Comment: Great find, but I dont know what Vendor name is? My magento directory is something like this: 'magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Plugin` and the links you suggested have `Create class VendorName/ModuleName/Model/Plugin/StoreFilterFixer.php`./ Is this the same directory >?

Comment: 'VendorName' should be replaced with your company/personal name, for core modules it is equal to `Magento`. See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/module-file-structure.html#file-struct-comp-mod