# Magento2 - How to filter product collection on category view

Tags: magento2, event-observer, collection, plugin

I'm trying to add filters to a product collection on the category page.

I wanted to create an observer that listens to catalog_product_collection_load_before, but I found out that the even is not fired anymore in the [changelog](https://github.com/diglin/magento2/blob/master/htdocs/magento/CHANGELOG.md).

How can I filter the product collection, without this observer. Should I use a plugin? Where to start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I did figure it out myself based on [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91278/magento-2-can-you-filter-by-store-id-using-a-product-repository). If anyone else faces this problem, the way to go is indeed to create a plugin.

Create the file frontend/di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection">
        <plugin name="sidebarFilters" type="Sebwite\Sidebar\Model\Plugin\SidebarFilter"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then create the plugin:

```
<?php namespace Sebwite\Sidebar\Model\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection as ProductCollection;

class SidebarFilter
{
    /**
     * aroundAddFieldToFilter method
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
     * @param \Closure                                                $proceed
     * @param                                                         $fields
     * @param null                                                    $condition
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     */
    public function aroundAddFieldToFilter(ProductCollection $collection, \Closure $proceed, $fields, $condition = null)
    {
        // Here we can modify the collection

        return $fields ? $proceed($fields, $condition) : $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some example ? I would like to filter by some custom attribute but can't find a way..

Comment: Hi Silvan do you know how to set default filter on each category?

Comment: @AkshayJindal just use the code above and add a filter on the collection: $collection->addAttributeToFilter('brand', ['in' => ['brand1', brand2']]);

Comment: This solution no working for the LayeredNavigation and pagination