# Having pagination issue with collection with addAttributeToFilter

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection

I'm having issue with the pagination and the layered navigation on filtered product collection. The goal is to filter the products by a customer attribute and show only products related to that attribute. The filter is fine except that I get more pages than really available. By example, a certain filter would return 10 products (which is correct) but give me 3 pages of 12 products (page 2 and page 3 doesn't show anything but the pager still show 3 pages). Same thing for the layered navigation on the left. I got results from not available products. By example, the color filter shows 2 products matching this color, but once clicked, no product is listed (it is normal, there is no blue product for that filter) but the results are still showing.

Based on [that post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101145/magento2-how-to-filter-product-collection-on-category-view)

di.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection">
        <plugin name="sidebarFilters" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\SidebarFilter"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

Sidebarfilter.php:

```
<?php namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection as ProductCollection;

class SidebarFilter
{
    /**
     * aroundAddFieldToFilter method
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
     * @param \Closure                                                $proceed
     * @param                                                         $fields
     * @param null                                                    $condition
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     */
    public function aroundAddFieldToFilter(ProductCollection $collection, \Closure $proceed, $fields, $condition = null)
    {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('brand',[ 'nin' => array(31, 32, 33) ]);

        return $fields ? $proceed($fields, $condition) : $collection;
    }
}
```

Everything is fine except pagination and layered navigation.

Thanks for help !

Comment: Papamike, did you find a solution to this? Or maybe a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

I, too, am having the very same issue - filtering works perfectly fine, but no matter where I perform the filtering, the LayeredNavigation will not work correctly.

Whilst I can't "comment", hopefully this "partial answer" can help you along?

By moving the filtering into a `CollectionFilter`, pagination works fine for me.

My di.xml:

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter" type="Company\Plugin\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter"/>
```

The `CollectionFilter`:

```
public function filter($collection, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category) {
        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect($this->catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addUrlRewrite($category->getId())
            ->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

            $filterBy = {custom code in here}

            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('supplier_code', array('IN' => $filterBy));

    }
```

I am just not sure if the LayeredNavigation is working correctly, or filtering must be performed earlier in the execution chain.

Can anyone else shed some light on this?