# Proper way to get product collection with store specific values in admin area

Tags: magento2, multistore, magento-2.0, product-collection, service-contract

For a custom indexer, I need to load a product collection with the attribute values for a given store, while not in a store context.

As it has been established in [Magento 2: How to Filter a Product Collection By Store ID](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91273/magento-2-how-to-filter-a-product-collection-by-store-id/91285?noredirect=1#comment163086_91285), `ProductRepository::getList()` does not have a store id parameter and also does not understand `store_id` as filter in the SearchCriteria parameter.

In the comments above, @IgorMinyaylo explains that in the REST APIs it is done by the store id URL part:

```
http://<magento_host>/rest/<store_code>/
```

So I looked how the `Webapi` module processes this part and found:

```
/**
 * Process path info
 *
 * @param string $pathInfo
 * @return string
 * @throws NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function process($pathInfo)
{
    $pathParts = $this->stripPathBeforeStorecode($pathInfo);
    $storeCode = $pathParts[0];
    $stores = $this->storeManager->getStores(false, true);
    if (isset($stores[$storeCode])) {
        $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeCode);
        $path = '/' . (isset($pathParts[1]) ? $pathParts[1] : '');
    } else if ($storeCode === self::ALL_STORE_CODE) {
        $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore(\Magento\Store\Model\Store::ADMIN_CODE);
        $path = '/' . (isset($pathParts[1]) ? $pathParts[1] : '');
    } else {
        $path = '/' . implode('/', $pathParts);
    }
    return $path;
}
```

The relevant line is:

```
        $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeCode);
```

But this sets the "current store" as global state. This is fine for an API request, but I would rather avoid it when I'm actually in admin or cron context. The risk of undesired side effects is too high.

I also looked at the core indexers but those operate on a level of implementation detail which would not be a good fit for an extension.

---

So how can I achieve the same without `$storeManager->setCurrentStore()`? Do I have to construct my collection manually instead of using the repository? Can I use store emulation?

In [Magento 2: Can you Filter By store_id Using a Product Repository](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91278/magento-2-can-you-filter-by-store-id-using-a-product-repository) a plugin for the product collection is proposed as fix, which makes it possible to add `store_id` as SearchCriteria parameter. It's good enough as a workaround, but does not seem "right" to me.