# Wrong store_id in product collection

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-collection, msi, multi-source-inventory

I need to cycle products collection for each store. But the method `$collection->addStoreFilter($store)` seems to not work properly. I also tried to $collection->setStore and setStoreId.

**The problem is: at first cycle everything is ok and the collection has results. But on all the next cycles i get 0 results.**

Debugging i saw that the query is wrong:

**First cycle query:** `` SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`\n INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id=2 WHERE (e.created_in <= \'1580479620\') AND (e.updated_in > \'1580479620\') ``

**Second cycle query** `` SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`\n INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=2 AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id=2 WHERE (e.created_in <= \'1580479620\') AND (e.updated_in > \'1580479620\') ``

**Third cycle query:** `` SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`\n INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=3 AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id=2 WHERE (e.created_in <= \'1580479620\') AND (e.updated_in > \'1580479620\') ``

As you can see the condition `AND cat_index.store_id=` changes. But the inner join is always on catalog_category_product_index_store1. Should change with store2 and 3.

This join is generated here: \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::_applyProductLimitations line 2033:

```
$this->getSelect()->join(
      ['cat_index' => $this->tableMaintainer->getMainTable($this->getStoreId())],
      $joinCond,
      ['cat_index_position' => 'position']
);
```

$this->getStoreId() returns always 1

My code is:

```
        foreach ($this->storeManager->getStores() as $store) {
            $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $collection->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
            $collection->addStoreFilter($store->getId());
           // $collection->setStoreId($store->getId());
            $collection->load();

            $products = $collection->getItems();
        }
```

Before using collection i tried with productRepository and searchCriteria but the result is the same. Also tried store emulation and clear collection. Any ideas?

PS: i am using MSI on Magento 2.3.3 EE

Comment: Please refer this link :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91273/magento-2-how-to-filter-a-product-collection-by-store-id

Comment: @MohitPatel i already use addStoreFilter method and it works if you don't cycle stores